# ValueError: X has 54 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting 53 features as input

Tags: predictive-modeling, random-forest, decision-trees, data-analysis, interpretation

I am analysing and prediction [2023 Cricket World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Cricket_World_Cup) based on previous given dataset.

This is Exploratary analysis:
[image]

Feature selection and Training model:
[image]

Applying Random forest classifier algorithm:
[image]

Evaluating the best model on test data:
[image]

Interpret the model results:
[image]

---

> ValueError: X has 54 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting
> 53 features as input.

---

**My Attempt:**
I tried to use `from sklearn import *` but it is not working. I also tried to drop columns from `pred_set` but not working. Can you please hint me what should fix here in order to Interpret the model results !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you do pred_set.drop(["Winner"], axis=1) you need to add inPlace=True, or assign to a new dataframe, otherwise nothing happens.

```
pred_set.drop(["Winner"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Nice! It works!!